# do_decimal_point and do_thousands_sep Not Working

Tags: c++, locale, currency-formatting

[`do_decimal_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/decimal_point) and [`do_thousands_sep`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct/thousands_sep) seem to be completely ignored by my stream.

What I want is to do is use a period for my `thousands_sep` and a comma for my `decimal_point` in [`get_money`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_money). So I override [`moneypunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/moneypunct) but it is just ignored :(

```
struct punct_facet : public moneypunct<char> {
    char_type do_decimal_point() const { return ','; }
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const { return '.'; }
};

int main()
{
    istringstream USCurrency("1,234.56 -1,234.56 1.234,56 -1.234,56");
    USCurrency.imbue(locale(locale("en-US"), new punct_facet));
    int index = 0;
    long double value;

    do{
        value = 0.0;
        USCurrency >> get_money(value, true);
        cout << ++index << ": " << value << endl;
    } while (value == 123456.0 || value == -123456.0);
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this to just output:

> 1: 123

But instead I get:

> 1: 123456
>   2: -123456
>   3: 123

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Visual Studio 2013, in case that may be obvious from the `"en-US"`.

**EDIT:**

I've discovered when I place a break-point in `do_decimal_point` or `do_thousands_sep` that it is never hit. I'm not sure why not, but that information seems to be relevant to the problem.

Comment: `get_money` uses `moneypunct` facet, not `numpunct`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have to say that sounded very promising, but when I change `numpunct` to `moneypunct` in my example, I just get: `1: 1` for output. It seems with my custom `moneypunct` it also needs me to call `get_money(value, true)`, then I get the original output. Either way it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Why would you expect only `1: 123`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Money should only be calculated to two decimal places in `en-US`. (That's why the final statement of what I actually get *is* `123`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is really just an explanation of the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31390621/2642059).

Both the copy constructor and assignment opperator are deleted by the `moneypunct` implementation. Which leaves two bad options for constructing `punct_facet`:

1. Duplicate all `moneypunct` members in `punct_facet` and call all `moneypunct` virtual functions in the `punct_facet` constructor to initialize them. This has the obvious drawback of a `punct_facet` object being twice as fat as it should be and it's constructor running longer than is strictly necessary.
2. Use pointers and a compiler specific knowledge of object layout to effect a copy construction from a `moneypunct` to a `punct_facet`. This has the obvious drawback of not being cross-platform and intentionally disregarding the standard implementation's design.

For this answer I have elected bad option 2, because the implementation of `moneypunct` is already compiler specific for any construction argument other than: `""`, `"C"`, or `"POSIX"` and because there is an [open bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1524749/inheriting-from-moneypunct-requires-use-of-unavailable-construction-information) against the deleted `moneypunct` copy constructor and assignment operator. (Incidentally if the `moneypunct` construction argument is adjusted option 2 [works in gcc 5.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4a1d88b560d6d1b) as well, but it will *not* work in Clang 3.6.0.) Hopefully Microsoft will provide a more functional workaround for that bug soon and we won't have to use either bad option.

So if `punct_facet` is implemented like this:

```
template <typename T>
class punct_facet : public T {
private:
    void Init(const T* money){
        const auto vTablePtrSize = sizeof(void*);

        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + vTablePtrSize, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(money) + vTablePtrSize, sizeof(T) - vTablePtrSize);
    }
protected:
    typename T::char_type do_decimal_point() const {
        return typename T::char_type(',');
    }

    typename T::char_type do_thousands_sep() const {
        return typename T::char_type('.');
    }
public:
    punct_facet(){
        Init(&use_facet<T>(cout.getloc()));
    }

    punct_facet(const T* money){
        Init(money);
    }
};
```

You can construct with either of the `punct_facet` constructors and you will get your expected output:

> 123

To use the default constructor you'd need to add `cout.imdue(locale("en-US"));` at the top of `main` and change your `imdue` statement to:

```
USCurrency.imbue(locale(locale("en-US"), new punct_facet<moneypunct<char, true>>()));
```

To use the custom constructor you'd only need to change your `imdue` statement to:

```
USCurrency.imbue(locale(locale("en-US"), new punct_facet<moneypunct<char, true>>(&use_facet<moneypunct<char, true>>(locale("en-US")))));
```

The default constructor is preferable as a discrepancy between your template type and your constructor argument could result in some bad behavior.

One minor note, your `USCurrency` is not using international currency format, so there's no need to use `moneypunct<char, true>`, `moneypunct<char>` will work just fine. Just remember to change it everywhere as a discrepancy between the template arguments to `punct_facet` and the arguments used in `get_money` will again result in the unexpected behavior you were seeing.