# locale Facet Constructor Ignored

Tags: c++, inheritance, locale, standards, facet

The [`locale` `Facet` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/locale):

> Constructs a copy of other except for the facet of type Facet (typically deduced from the type of the argument) which is installed from the argument facet. If facet is NULL, the constructed locale is a full copy of other. The locale constructed in this manner has no name.

I try to construct using my `Facet` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245857/do-decimal-point-and-do-thousands-sep-not-working), but when I put a break-point in my `do_decimal_point` and `do_thousands_sep` they are never called :(

I can see the `Facet` being passed in, but it's passed into standard library implementation files so I can't see if anything is ever done with it.

I've tried this on Visual Studio 2013, Clang 3.6.0, and gcc 4.9.2. *All* of them behave as though I had never passed in a `Facet` just using the other `locale`'s behavior.

I can't find any bugs against this constructor in any of the compilers. I think I'm doing this all the right way. Why can't I get `locale` to construct using my `Facet`?

**EDIT:**

At [the request of 0x499602D2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291004/locale-facet-constructor-ignored?noredirect=1#comment50582989_31291004) I have added an example. It's interesting to note that the `Facet` *does* seem to be picked up but *not* used with `get_money`. I'm linking a [live example of this](http://ideone.com/Iwrfqc) (which necessarily uses`locale("C")` instead of `locale("en-US")`):

```
class Foo : public std::moneypunct<char> {
protected:
    char_type do_decimal_point() const {
        cout << "Hit Foo::do_decimal_point";
        return ',';
    }
    char_type do_thousands_sep() const {
        cout << "Hit Foo::do_thousands_sep";
        return '.';
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout.imbue(locale(locale("en-US"), new Foo));

    const moneypunct<char>* temp = &use_facet<std::moneypunct<char>>(cout.getloc());

    cout << temp->decimal_point() << endl << temp->thousands_sep() << endl;

    istringstream USCurrency("1,234.56 -1,234.56 1.234,56 -1.234,56");
    USCurrency.imbue(cout.getloc());

    long double value;

    USCurrency >> get_money(value, true);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

> Hit Foo::do_thousands_sepHit Foo::do_decimal_point,
>   .

I would expect it to output:

> Hit Foo::do_thousands_sepHit Foo::do_decimal_point,
>   .
>   Hit Foo::do_thousands_sepHit Foo::do_decimal_point

**EDIT2:**

It appears that `moneypunct<char>` can't be inherited from as it doesn't get constructed properly, unless it is constructed internally by the `locale`. Which at least on Visual Studio is a problem because it determines whether to use `thousands_sep` by the `grouping`. The work around may be to completely reimplement `moneypunct<char>`'s functionality. I'm tinkering with that now. In the meantime I've also added a bug here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1524749/inheriting-from-moneypunct-requires-use-of-unavailable-construction-information

Comment: Could you please provide us an mcve?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've added an example, which to my surprise kind of invalidates this question... I need to do more research on how `get_money` works.

Comment: I'm getting the expected output [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f0c461fda32a17c).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Fascinating. Yet when I look at `value` only contains: 1. So even though gcc 5.1.0 supports `locale`'s `Facet` constructor `get_money` still doesn't work. So perhaps this should be written as a bug against Visual Studio 2013 and Clang 3.6.0. And some other bug should be written against gcc 5.1.0. I guess I should get on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is, `do_decimal_place` and `do_thousands_place` *are* respected by `get_money`. The difficulty is in the fact that the `moneypunct` that is being inherited from is being default constructed, so the supporting information to direct `get_money` to call `do_decimal_place` and `do_thousands_place` is not being set up.

Visual Studio's implementation of `moneypunct` provides two public constructors:

1. `moneypunct()`
2. `moneypunct(const _Locinfo& _Lobj, size_t _Refs = 0, bool _Isdef = false)`

`locale`'s constructor calls the 2nd `moneypunct` constructor. Creating a proper `_Locinfo` is the crux of the problem as that information seems to be implementation specific. The [linked Visual Studio Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1524749/inheriting-from-moneypunct-requires-use-of-unavailable-construction-information) requests a way to construct a functional `moneypunct` without access to implementation details. In lieu of this information all `moneypunct` fields must be cooked up.

Since this question is about extending an expected working `moneypunct` the easiest way to do that would be to use an assignment operator or copy constructor. *Bad news:* both of those are deleted. So  `punct_facet(const money_punct&)` will need to be written internally implementing the behavior of a copy constructor. The values that need to be copied correspond to all the virtual functions that need to be overridden and by `punct_facet`. In the end your class will end up looking similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
class punct_facet : public T {
protected:
    typename T::string_type m_grouping;
    typename T::string_type m_curr_symbol;
    typename T::string_type m_positive_sign;
    typename T::string_type m_negative_sign;
    int m_frac_digits;
    typename T::pattern m_pos_format;
    typename T::pattern m_neg_format;

    typename T::char_type do_decimal_point() const {
        return typename T::char_type(',');
    }

    typename T::char_type do_thousands_sep() const {
        return typename T::char_type('.');
    }

    typename T::string_type do_grouping() const {
        return m_grouping;
    }

    typename T::string_type do_curr_symbol() const {
        return m_curr_symbol;
    }

    typename T::string_type do_positive_sign() const {
        return m_positive_sign;
    }

    typename T::string_type do_negative_sign() const {
        return m_negative_sign;
    }

    int do_frac_digits() const {
        return m_frac_digits;
    }

    typename T::pattern do_pos_format() const {
        return m_pos_format;
    }

    typename T::pattern do_neg_format() const {
        return m_neg_format;
    }
public:
    punct_facet(const T& defaultFacet) : m_grouping(defaultFacet.grouping()),
                                         m_curr_symbol(defaultFacet.curr_symbol()),
                                         m_positive_sign(defaultFacet.positive_sign()),
                                         m_negative_sign(defaultFacet.negative_sign()),
                                         m_frac_digits(defaultFacet.frac_digits()),
                                         m_pos_format(defaultFacet.pos_format()),
                                         m_neg_format(defaultFacet.neg_format()) {}
};
```

**EDIT:**

This solution is cross platform but it is also unsatisfactory, because all the members that had to be added to `punct_facet` *already exist* in `moneypunct`. I am not aware of a clean workaround for this fattening. A compiler specific hack is available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31454039/2642059

This would result in a `punct_facet` that looked more like this given that Visual Studio places the v-table pointer as the first item in the object layout:

```
template <typename T>
class punct_facet : public T {
private:
    void Init(const T* money){
        const auto vTablePtrSize = sizeof(void*);

        memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + vTablePtrSize, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(money) + vTablePtrSize, sizeof(T) - vTablePtrSize);
    }
protected:
    typename T::char_type do_decimal_point() const {
        return typename T::char_type(',');
    }

    typename T::char_type do_thousands_sep() const {
        return typename T::char_type('.');
    }
public:
    punct_facet(){
        Init(&use_facet<T>(cout.getloc()));
    }

    punct_facet(const T* money){
        Init(money);
    }
};
```

Incidentally this implementation of `punct_facet` is not supported in Clang 3.6.0 but *is* supported in gcc 5.1.0: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4a1d88b560d6d1b